# Batch file - creating folder based on date 1 day ahead

Tags: date, batch-file

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

mkdir "C:\Users\name\Desktop\%mm%%dd%%yy%\"

pause
```

-Is there a way to make it create the folder and name it 1 day in advanced. Today is 11/14 I want it to create it and name it 11/15? end up looking like 111514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of `cmd` magic. I took it from the script called [`TOMORROW.BAT`](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/MS_DOS/A_4196-Advanced-Batch-File-Programming-TOMORROW-BAT.html) and reworked a bit to match your variables.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a" 
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" 
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

:loop
  set /a DD+=1

  if %DD% gtr 31 (
    set DD=1
    set /a MM+=1

    if %MM% gtr 12 (
      set MM=1
      set /a YY+=1
      set /a YYYY+=1
    )
  )
xcopy /d:%MM%-%DD%-%YYYY% /l . .. >nul 2>&1 || goto loop

echo %DD%/%MM%/%YYYY%
mkdir "C:\Users\name\Desktop\%MM%%DD%%YY%\"
pause
```

The idea here is to use `/d` option of `xcopy` to validate the incremented date—otherwise we would need to handle months which have 28, 29, 30, or 31 days manually.

Comment: LOL it hurts my head trying to figure out what each line does, but it works wonders. Thanks