# Batch File timestamp for today and tomorrow

Tags: date, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that creates a new folder named after tomorrow's date, but I also need it to grab a file from a folder with today's date. My code is written so it only sets it by tomorrows date when I put %mm%%dd%%yy%. I need help editing it so it grabs both somehow. Here is my code

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem Retrieve data
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a" 
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" 
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

rem Remove padding from date elements and increase day
set /a "y=%YYYY%", "m=100%MM% %% 100", "d=(100%DD% %% 100)+1" 
rem Calculate month length
set /a "ml=30+((m+m/8) %% 2)" & if %m% equ 2 set /a "ml=ml-2+(3-y %% 4)/3-(99-y %% 100)/99+(399-y %% 400)/399"
rem Adjust day / month / year for tomorrow date
if %d% gtr %ml% set /a "d=1", "m=(m %% 12)+1", "y+=(%m%/12)"

rem Pad date elements and translate again to original variables
set /a "m+=100", "d+=100"
set "YYYY=%y%"
set "YY=%y:~-2%"
set "MM=%m:~-2%"
set "DD=%d:~-2%"

echo Tomorrow: %YYYY% / %MM% / %DD%

mkdir "C:\Users\name\Desktop\DNFB %mm%%dd%%yy%\"
mkdir "C:\Users\name\Desktop\DNFB %mm%%dd%%yy%\DNFB"

xcopy /s "C:\Users\name\Desktop\"DNFB %mm%%dd%%yy%"\file*.xls" "C:\Users\name\Desktop\DNFB %mm%%dd%%yy%\"
```

xcopy /s "C:\Users\name\Desktop\"DNFB %mm%%dd%%yy%"(TODAY)\file*.xls" "C:\Users\name\Desktop\DNFB %mm%%dd%%yy%(TOMORROW)\"
-Grabs a file from  a folder labeled "DNFB 010815" and paste it onto a folder "DNFB 010915"(tomorrows)

Is it even possible? Or is it too conflicting. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file - creating folder based on date 1 day ahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937878/batch-file-creating-folder-based-on-date-1-day-ahead)

Comment: I'm not asking to make a folder +1 day ahead. I'm trying to grab a file from today and place it into a folder +1 day ahead. The problem is I have to use %mm%%dd%%yy% and the batch right now takes that as tomorrow. So how do i make it read %mm%%dd%%yy% today and tomorrow

Comment: The same logic for calculating the next day (tomorrow) in a batch file applies, no matter what you're using the end result of that calculation to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the logic. Use more variables

```dos
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a" 
    set "td.YY=%dt:~2,2%" 
    set "td.YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
    set "td.MM=%dt:~4,2%"
    set "td.DD=%dt:~6,2%"

    rem Remove padding from date elements and increase day
    set /a "y=%td.YYYY%", "m=100%td.MM% %% 100", "d=(100%td.DD% %% 100)+1" 
    rem Calculate month length
    set /a "ml=30+((m+m/8) %% 2)" & if %m% equ 2 set /a "ml=ml-2+(3-y %% 4)/3-(99-y %% 100)/99+(399-y %% 400)/399"
    rem Adjust day / month / year for tomorrow date
    if %d% gtr %ml% set /a "d=1", "m=(m %% 12)+1", "y+=(%m%/12)"

    rem Pad date elements and set tomorrow variables
    set /a "m+=100", "d+=100"

    set "tm.YYYY=%y%"
    set "tm.YY=%y:~-2%"
    set "tm.MM=%m:~-2%"
    set "tm.DD=%d:~-2%"

    echo Today   : %td.YYYY% / %td.MM% / %td.DD%
    echo Tomorrow: %tm.YYYY% / %tm.MM% / %tm.DD%
```